# C# collections type constrained generics

Tags: c#, generics, collections, covariance, type-constraints

I am trying to do something in C# that is pretty straightforward in Java, using wildcard type-bounding.  I've tried to boil it down to only the Java code necessary to illustrate the problem (compiles):

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    public abstract SomeBindingList<? extends ParentClass> parentList();
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    private SomeBindingList<ChildClass> myList;

    public ChildClass() {
        // this could load from/bind to a database
        myList = new SomeBindingList<ChildClass>();
    }

    public SomeBindingList<? extends ParentClass> parentList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Perhaps I need to emphasize the following line since someone marked this as a duplicate:
**`SomeBindingList` is a 3rd-party `BindingList` so I can't change it.  It is parameterized and can't be replaced with a non-parameterized version.**

The problem, of course, is how to implement the `parentList()` method in the `ChildClass` to return a list that can be used as a list of `ParentClass` objects.

It seems like there should be some way to use the `where` keyword to provide a constrained type in C#, but I can't make it work (syntactically at least) with a class that already extends another class, i.e. `ChildClass`, and there doesn't seem to be a way to parameterize just the return value of a method (or a property).

I could make a new list and put all the `ChildClass` items in the new list as `ParentClass` items, but (aside from being kludgy) I was afraid that would interfere with the behavior of `SomeBindingList`.

I'm no C# expert, so I'm sure someone more familiar with the language knows the answer.  Thanks!

@CodeCaster -- I've tried many variations of C# code (this does not compile, and I can't find a variation that does):

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    public abstract List<T> parentList<T>() where T : ParentClass;
}

public class ChildClass {
    public List<ChildClass> myList;

    public ChildClass() {
        myList = new List<ChildClass>();
    }

    public override List<T> parentList<T>() where T : ParentClass {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

I've tried parameterizing `ChildClass<T>` but that just causes generation of a `List<ChildClass<T>>` which is not a `List<T>`

Comment: Can you then show the code you wrote and what issues that has?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior -- I think your solution was also a good one and might be useful for others if you want to post it here as well.  If I were writing the code myself from scratch, I would probably try that.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue here is related to the desired co-variance of the relationship between the inheritance hierarchy of the generic 3rd-party `SomeBindingList<T>` class and the hierarchy of the types used as parameters.

First, let me give you code that will compile:

```
public interface ISomeBindingList<out T>
{
}

public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public abstract ISomeBindingList<ParentClass> parentList();
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    private ISomeBindingList<ChildClass> myList;

    public ChildClass()
    {
        // this could load from/bind to a database
        // myList = new SomeBindingList<ChildClass>(); // <-- we need to figure out this
    }

    public override ISomeBindingList<ParentClass> parentList()
    {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

C# does not provide generic type co-variance for classes. But it does for interfaces. You will have to think outside the box and implement a trivial adapter for your 3rd-party `SomeBindingList<T>`, which implements only the lifted members that are **co-variantly compatible**, that is: those members where `T` only occurs as output.

For example, assuming `SomeBindingList<T>` contains a method `T Get()`, you would **lift this member to an adapter interface**, and create a **trivial adapter implementation**.

This would be the complete code:

```
public interface ISomeBindingList<out T>
{
    T Get();
}

public class SomeBindingListAdapter<T> : SomeBindingList<T>, ISomeBindingList<T>
{
}

public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public abstract ISomeBindingList<ParentClass> parentList();
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    private ISomeBindingList<ChildClass> myList;

    public ChildClass()
    {
        // this could load from/bind to a database
        myList = new SomeBindingListAdapter<ChildClass>();
    }

    public override ISomeBindingList<ParentClass> parentList()
    {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know that about interfaces.  This works well in my case where I am working with pre-existing code.  The less I can change it the better, and this means I don't have to parameterize the classes, which would require changes throughout the code.  Cheers!